# How to use Fabric in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, fabricjs, gatsby

I use fabric in gatsby all fine but when I build the site I get an error:

```
ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating SSR bundle failed

Unexpected character '' (1:0)

File: node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node:1:0
```

the error comes from the import fabric this code below
because when I remove the import all goes fine

```
import { fabric } from "fabric"
```

I tried this code also I get the same error

```
const { fabric } = (() => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return require("fabric")
  }
})()
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that fabric is using a global object (such as `window` or `document`) to make their stuff. `gatsby develop` is compiled in the browser-side, where those global objects are always defined. On the other hand, when you run `gatsby build` the code is compiled in the Node server, where those variables obviously are not defined yet.

You have several ways to bypass that limitation.

- In the component where you are importing the fabric dependency, just use:

  ```
  if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
     const module = require("module")
  }
  ```

  In your case, you will not able to destructurate `fabric` as a `prop` because it's not defined yet, you will need to use a `useEffect` hook.
- Fix the third-party module importation by adding in your `gatsby-node.js` the following:

  ```
    if (stage === "build-html") {
      actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /fabric/,
              use: loaders.null(),
            },
          ],
        },
      })
    }
  }
  ```

  With this snippet basically, you are setting a `null` loader to the conflictive module in webpack's configuration to avoid the code-breaking. `/fabric/` is a regular expression that will match the folder under `node_modules` so check that the path and naming are both correct

You can check [Debugging HTML builds](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) for more information.

Comment: instead of having the null loader on fabric, try have it on jsdom and canvas dep.